# CMS page URLs in Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to figure out Magento's routing because I need it for mod_rewrite. I have made several CMS pages in Magento itself; now I am wondering how to pass on $_GET variables.

For example:

```
http://www.magento.nl/catpage?catid=3
```

How should this URL look the Magento way? I tried:

```
http://www.magento.nl/cms/catpage/index/index/catid/3
```

Unfortunately this isn't working. Could someone help me out here, it's the missing link I am looking for.  :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to change mod_rewrite or understand the router/controller/action process yourself. Magento already has rewriting abilities and CMS pages have an "url-key" which is used to make the public URL value. You have finer control via the "Catalog > URL Rewrite Management" too.

Comment: this gives a problem when dealing with get post so u do have to understand how the controller works otherwise u cannot deal with the get post anyways i found my page id in the controller from the cms page and through there i could made the rewrite..